# quick sort in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to use quick sort for my project but it doesn't work. And I can't figure out where the bug is. Anyone who can help me figure it out? Thank you.

```
void quicksort(int arr[],int a, int b){
    if(a<=b){
        int key=arr[a];
        int index=a;
        int i=a, j=b;
        while(i<=j){
            for(;arr[j]>key;--j);
            int temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=key;
            arr[index]=temp;
            index=j;
            for(;arr[i]<key;++i);
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=key;
            arr[index]=temp;
            index=i;
            }
        quicksort(arr,a,index);
        quicksort(arr,index,b);
        }
    else return;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have a bug? Is your program crashing? Producing an unexpected result? Or think about it this way: if you sent this question as an email to your prof, do you really think your prof would be inclined to respond?

Comment: If you're using C++ you should avoid `qsort` and use `std::sort` instead. By comparison, `sort` will be safer, easier to use, and likely faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner loop does this:

- Check from the right-hand-side of the array to find an element that should be on the left side of `key`.
- Swap any found element with `key`, located at `index` and update `index` to `key`'s new location
- Check from the left-hand-side of the array to find an element that should be on the right side of `key`.
- Swap any found element with `key`, located at `index` and update `index` to `key`'s new location

Why in the world would you want to do this? You should do this:

- Check from the right-hand-side of the array to find an element that should be on the left side of `key`.
- Check from the left-hand-side of the array to find an element that should be on the right side of `key`.
- If found, swap them. If not, put the pivot in the right position and exit loop

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that shuffling the `key` around in your version of quicksort may be the culprit of your problem. The best way to find out is to debug your code step by step and see where it goes wrong.

Here's the implementation according to my suggestion above, together with a few test-cases:

```
void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}

void quicksort0(int arr[], int a, int b) {
    if (a >= b)
        return;

    int key = arr[a];
    int i = a + 1, j = b;
    while (i < j) {
        while (i < j && arr[j] >= key)
            --j;
        while (i < j && arr[i] <= key)
            ++i;
        if (i < j)
            swap(arr, i, j);
    }
    if (arr[a] > arr[i]) {
        swap(arr, a, i);
        quicksort0(arr, a, i - 1);
        quicksort0(arr, i + 1, b);
    } else { // there is no left-hand-side
        quicksort0(arr, a + 1, b);
    }
}

void quicksort(int arr[], int len) {
    quicksort0(arr, 0, len - 1);
}

int main() {
    int a1[] = { };
    int a2[] = { 1 };
    int a3[] = { 1, 1 };
    int a4[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a5[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int a6[] = { 9, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 0, 2, 7, 5 };

    quicksort(a1, 0);
    quicksort(a2, 1);
    quicksort(a3, 2);
    quicksort(a4, 5);
    quicksort(a5, 5);
    quicksort(a6, 10);
    quicksort(a6, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C already comes with [qsort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) function that does quicksort.

Comment: `qsort` doesn't necessarily implement quick sort.

Comment: the algorithm of `qsort` is unspecified by the Standard: `qsort` should not be confused with quicksort.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

```
arr[j]=key;
```

because you should put your pivot only once at popper place

and calling

```
    quicksort(arr,a,index);
    quicksort(arr,index,b);
```

also smells, because you have botl low and high index same.

Check this great video on qucksort from google (includes lot of code and explanation)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMnn0Jq0J-E